# Extra Reputation lost from User removed?

Tags: discussion, reputation

I understand what `User removed` means when losing (or gaining) Reputation. I encountered it fro the first time last week. However, when I checked my Rep. tab recently, this showed up:

[image]

So did I lose 34 or 24 Reputation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that the other 10 rep you lost was also due user removal, but the posts where you got the rep back have all been deleted. Not sure if there's a way for you to see this in that tab yourself, but you could try checking off the "Show removed posts" button zaq mentioned.